# Put a youtube iframe on an other frame with icon close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I put an iframe youtube on a frame with icon close.
example:-
If I want to put the iframe below on frame with icon close, and if I click on icon close the iframe youtube will disappear, how can I do this?

```
<iframe width="440" height="215" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OyRQio7GfLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure by 100% if this is what did you expect, but I hope I've helped you.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  $("#x").addClass('hide');
});
```

```css
.frame {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  display: block;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frame">
  <button class='button'>X</button>
  <iframe id='x' class='content' width="440" height="215" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OyRQio7GfLU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. You can also stylish the div/button in your own way aswell as making the whole div disappearing, after clicking the button.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with CSS without JavaScript:

1. Wrap your iframe in a div.
2. Add an `<input type='checkbox'>` above the div and iframe.
3. Add a `<label>` after the `<input type='checkbox'>`.
4. Hide `<input type='checkbox'>` with `display:none`.
5. Style the div to be invisible with `opacity:0`, or `visibility:hidden`*
6. Add this ruleset:

> ```
> input:checked + label + div {
>       visibility: visible;
>   }
> ```

*`display:none` and `display:block` works as well but it has the possibility to disrupt layout.

The following Snippet includes commented details

#### SNIPPET

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
#chx1 {
  display: none;
}
label {
  font-size: 40px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fC3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label:hover {
  color: #0ff;
}
/* This is the style of expanding div */

.expand {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
  width: 480px;
  transition: opacity .4s, max-height 1s linear .3s;
}
/* This is the style of expanding div after checkbox is checked */

/* The :checked pseudo-class is associated to expanding div with adjacent sibling selectors */

#chx1:checked + label + .expand {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 270px;
}
```

```html
<!--Make sure the checkbox has an id-->
<input id='chx1' type='checkbox'>

<!--Make sure the label has a for that 
has the same value as checkbox id value-->
<label for='chx1'>✦</label>

<!--This is the expanding div that wraps around iframe-->
<div class='expand'>

  <!--This is your Youtube iframe inside of expanding iframe-->
  <iframe width="480" height="270" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/o0u4M6vppCI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```